# How to get CLI access from Daedalus installation?

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, node

I have a Daedalus wallet running which is a full node so in theory, I should get all the CLI functionality from that one install, how do I access it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daedalus has its own `cardano-node` instance, so you can specify the node's socket variable and use it for `cardano-cli` purposes.

First, launch Daedalus, and click on Help > Daedalus Diagnostics. Under the "Core Info" section, the "Daedalus State Directory" specifies the filepath that Daedalus uses on your computer. There should be a socket variable (likely named `cardano-node.socket`) in this directory which you can point to in your `bashrc` file.

In your CLI, run: `nano ~/.bashrc`

Now, scroll down and add the following line to the bashrc file:

`export CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=<PATH_TO_SOCKET_IN_DAEDALUS_STATE_DIRECTORY>`

Exit the bashrc file and run: `source ~/.bashrc`

Make sure cardano-cli is installed and is in your $PATH. You should now be able to run `cardano-cli` commands using Daedalus' `cardano-node` instance.

Comment: Is there a quick command to check if its using deadulus? I have both the repo and Deadlus installed and cant seem to figure out which one node its using (also I have verified all the steps were done exactly as you said and its a beautiful and succinct explanation thanks man).

Comment: Not sure if there is a "quick" command for this. `cardano-cli` will connect with whichever node's socket variable is specified in the `bashrc` file. You can probably use commands like `ps aux` or `htop` to query which processes are running, but if both are running simultaneously, I would just check the bashrc file with `nano ~/.bashrc`

Comment: thanks man i think i might turn this into a bash script

Comment: Can't seem to run cardano-cli because it says not found, how do you run it? I think it's not found because it's part of nix maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Deadalus menu, and you should see a menu item that says "Open a Marlowe terminal", and a terminal will open with Marlowe Cli installed.

Comment: is the marlowe terminal diffrent from the CLI or the same thing with a different name?